# Get user stories that contains text "mobile or testing" using 2.0RC1

Tags: rally

How can i get the user stories having text "mobile" or "testing" using 2.0rc1

I could get the user stories that contains both "mobile and testing"

eg : Userstory for mobile testing

i did this

```
context: {
                            project :'xxxx',
                            projectScopeUp: false,
                            projectScopeDown: true
                        },
                        filters: [
                            {
                                property: 'Name',
                                operator: 'contains',
                                value: 'mobile'
                            },{
                                property: 'Name',
                                operator: 'contains',
                                value: 'testing'
                            }
                        ]
```

But i want the stories that contains anyone of the text mobile or testing.

eg :

- userstory for mobile
- userstory for testing

Answer (score 0):

By default the syntax above uses AND operator. If you want to use OR operator, try:

```
var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                                property: 'Name',
                                operator: 'contains',
                                value: 'mobile'
                            });

                            filter = filter.or({
                                property: 'Name',
                                operator: 'contains',
                                value: 'testing'  
                            });
                            filter.toString();
```

and then add filter to the store config:

```
filters : [filter]
```